# OpenCL program on FPGA performs slower than on CPU

Tags: opencl, fpga

I am learning to use opencl on FPGA and wrote a progarm to implement of the [Smith–Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).But the results is that program on CPU performs faster than on FPGA.

Here is my kernel code:

```
    __kernel void __attribute__ ((reqd_work_group_size(512,512,1)))
krnl_sw(
     __global int* ref,
     __global int* alt,
     __global int* sw,
     const int match,
     const int mismatch,
     const int open,
     const int extend,
     const int ncol,
     const int nrow
     ) {

 int col = get_global_id(0);
 int row = get_global_id(1);

 for (k = 2;k<ncol+nrow-1;k++)
{
    if(col + row == k)
    { 
            up_score = sw[(row - 1)*ncol + col] + extend*(row-1) + open ;
            left_score = sw[row*ncol + col - 1] + extend*(row-1) + open ;
            up_left_score = sw[(row - 1)*ncol + col - 1] + diag_score(ref[col - 1], alt[row - 1], match, mismatch);
            sw[row*ncol + col] = max(up_score, left_score);
            sw[row*ncol + col] = max(up_left_score, sw[row*ncol + col]);

    }
}
  return;
}
```

Code on cpu:

```
for (i = 1;i < ncol;i++)
{
    for (j = 1;j< nrow;j++)
    {
            up_score = sw[j - 1][i] + extend*(j-1)+open;
            left_score = sw[j][i - 1] + extend * (i - 1) + open;
            up_left_score = sw[j - 1][i - 1] + diag_score(ref[i - 1], alt[j - 1], match, mismatch);
            sw[j][i] = max(up_score, left_score);
            sw[j][i] = max(up_left_score, sw[j][i]);

    }
}
```

Anything wrong with the kernel code?

Comment: Your post is far from clear. 1/ *"performs worse then on CPU "* is relative. What is worse, slower? more power? 2/ What FPGA? 3/ I don not recognize your 'kernel' code as FPGA code. How did you convert that to gates? 4/ If this runs on an FPGA what clock does it run at? Have you tried to speed it up. e.g. introduce pipelining?

Comment: @Oldfart: OpenCL is a tool for automatic conversion of "software" to GPU cores, or FPGA logic, etc, sort of like SystemC.  I'm sure an expert *can* get as good results with those as with say VHDL or Verilog, but the abstraction layer is deceiving, since you have to understand not only the underlying logic elements, but also the translation layer quite thoroughly to get good performance.

Comment: I don't understand why you loop over `ncol+nrow` in kernel. Your CPU code iterates over a matrix and for each element computes somethings. You should have as many work items as matrix elements. I think that's what you did `512,512,1` so thats  `512x512` element matrix. The `col` and `row` var in kernel do the job of `i` and `j` in cpu code. So there is no need for a loop.

Comment: @gallickgunner: Due to the data dependence between matrix elements (each next element depends on the other ones - left to it, up to it, and left-up to it),so I loop over ncol+nrow to calculate anti-diagonals elements from upper left to lower right，in parallel,as illustrated in this picture: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SqWd.png)

Comment: I still don't understand the need for the loop xD Your CPU code, loops over every element and calculates the value using up, left and up left scores. Your GPU code should do the same thing, You should have as many work items as your elements that is `ncol*nrow` Then all you need to write are the lines inside the nested forloop from the CPU code in your kernel.